# In a room filled with mirrors, and mirrors only, what do you see?

Tags: science-in-society

Just imagine there is a room, a spherical room, and contained inside are mirrors.  These mirrors are constantly reflecting off of each other.  A sphere made out of mirrors, so to speak; Do you see an image of the mirror that is being reflected on the mirror, but what do you see on the other mirror now?  I guess what I'm asking, is, what would the inside of such a sphere of mirrors look like?

Comment: It would be dark, because you have no light source. If you have a light, you see images of yourself and the light source from various angles in every direction. This is because every line of sight ends on either you or the light.

Comment: Firstly, why not put this in the "answers," area instead of the comments.  Secondly, assuming there is light and nothing is being obstructed inside of the sphere, but you are able to see inside, what, then, would you see?

Comment: You're new to the site, but anything that short should generally go in comments, where frodoskywalker put it. Not enough for a full answer, but helpful. That's a comment.

Comment: You would just see yourself/the light distorted in different ways depending on where you are and where you are looking. What a strange thing to ask honestly... In addition know you can do use the '@' sign followed by a username to respond to someone. For example: @frodoskywalker. Now frodoskywalker will be notified of this comment.

Comment: You don't see anything, because you aren't in the room and there is no light in the room.

Comment: Can I just ask, am I inside this room or am I somehow observing the mirrors without being in the room?

Comment: You're outside of the room, but say that you have some sort of super natural ability to see inside of the room without any presence or matter occupying the space that you're seeing.  There is light being projected magically as well, but the sources of your sight and where the light is coming from is irrelevant.

Comment: @NateDukes You might want to put your answers to those questions, as to observation, so people have a better handle on the question. May be better in physics stack exchange than here? I see someone has downvoted it for not being about world-building, and...yes, this is a real-world physics problem.

Comment: @frodoskywalker, only if you are in the geometric center of the sphere.

Comment: Either you would see nothing (because there's no light source) or this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zRP82omMX0g

Comment: @ErinThursby I think it's tricky because, when factoring in the comments, the scenario is too far removed from reality to be well received on Physics.SE, but the question is formulated in a format that belongs there.  Reading between the lines, I think the OP didn't realize how much magic and otherwise unrealistic handwaving was being invoked in the contrived setup so was expecting a physics based answer.

Comment: Vsauce did a great indepth video about this [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zRP82omMX0g).

Comment: You can see something like this https://www.instagram.com/p/r9oTZBTDWn/?taken-by=kaktutusidet

This foto is taken is in hexagonal room with walls of mirrors.
Everything is repeat to eternity and than fades to dark in about 30-40 iterations.. For spherical room - don't know(

Answer (score 4):

From your comments:

> You're outside of the room, but say that you have some sort of super natural ability to see inside of the room without any presence or matter occupying the space that you're seeing. There is light being projected magically as well, but the sources of your sight and where the light is coming from is irrelevant.

What you see will be magical.  I say this because these criteria are sufficiently far from real physics that only magic can tell you what you will see.

The most you could possibly see would be the light source, so where the light is coming from is highly relevant.  Realistically, though, there will be losses in this system.  The mirrors are imperfect, so they'll absorb some of the energy in each reflection.  You'll see an array of dots for every path which eventually intersects with the light source.

If the mirrors are also magically perfect, then we have an interesting system.  The energy in the room keeps going up because we have a light source in there, but it's never diminishing because we've magically kept all possible losses down.  The light will get brighter and brighter, though you won't be able to observe it because observing it would involve absorbing some of those photons and we've decided we're not doing that.

This creates an interesting little battery of sorts.  You just keep piling up energy.  In theory, if you had just 100W of light going into that mirrored room, after about 20,000 years you could have the energy of a nuclear bomb stored up in there (Little Boy yielded $6\cdot10^{13} \text{J}$ of energy).

At some point we would expect some quantum mechanics effects to kick in.  I'm no expert in this, so I'm not exactly certain what it would look like.  However, I would expect that some resonant frequencies would form in that room so you would have some places that are brighter and some that are dimmer.

But in all fairness, the amount of magic involved in getting to that point is so great, if you don't like the quantum physics answer, you should feel free to make up your own!

Comment: If there were a perfect mirror there would never be any photon loss--I think it would be blinding and for sure quantum mechanics would kick in!

Comment: I'd upvote this but I'm too new to the site.  So I can't.  Thanks for answering my question.

Comment: @NateDukes You can accept the answer. There should be a tick below the voting arrows. Clicking this shows that this is our preferred answer and will give both you and the person who answered some rep.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a light, and assuming the light is some magical point source, you will see yourself on every surface, since you are the only thing in the room.

Assuming a perfectly curved mirror, you will be able to see as much of yourself as your field of vision. For example, if your field of vision is 120 degrees, you will see your face in whichever direction you are looking at, in at your peripheral vision, a view of your face from up to 60 degrees from the front in each direction.

Answer (score 1):

Let's talk about light first, as frodoskywalker did in their comment.

You've made this a sphere rather than your standard hall of mirrors, so the source of light and where it comes from will be very important. Simply saying that it's lit, is not enough. Where is the light coming from? A ceiling light source? Magically omni directional? You've placed tagged this science, so this detail is actually very important to what you might see.

Second point: are the mirrors sectioned and angled? Or is it all one piece? Most standard mirrors do not feature a curve to them, but all these mirrors might, or it could be a bit like being on the inside of a disco ball, but in reverse, with lots of square flat mirrors connected over a curved surface. We would need to know how big the mirrors are and how curved they are. The more curved they are, the more likely there will be a distortion. Same too for the floor.

The quality of the mirrors and how much it reflects is also an important consideration. See [this answe](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/55254/two-mirrors-facing-each-other)r on another stack exchange regarding infinite reflection.

In short, it says that there's no such thing as infinite reflection.

> In classical physics the electromagnetic waves that create the
>   reflections are uniform and the energy loss due to the reflection (
>   depending on the material of the glass) will be what will make the
>   reflections fainter and fainter , but the process is continuous and
>   the limit will be a limit in luminosity. In principle a totally
>   reflecting material would have no limit, going to infinite reflections
>   as time goes to infinity. {corrected from original statement that the
>   wavefronts are instantaneous: Maxwells equations obey special
>   relativity i.e. the velocity c of light is finite}
>
> Reality is quantum mechanical and also special relativity dependent.
>
> With special relativity in the problem it will take time to reach the
>   next reflection, so even for a total reflector infinity will also be
>   reached only at infinite time, during observation, though there will
>   be an enormous number of reflections.
>
> Quantum mechanically there can not be a totally reflecting mirror,
>   even in a thought problem. There will always be a probability of
>   absorption and thus a termination of the wavefront eventually, the
>   images getting less and less defined until they become individual
>   photons and finally totally absorbed .

Now, I assume in your question that the room is not empty, that there is, in fact, a person standing in the center taking it in--but that's an assumption. You may be asking about what the room would look like were it empty. In that case, where, how and what the light source is becomes very important, because then it would be reflecting the light back and forth bouncing off all the mirrors--and that is what an invisible person would see. Unless it's magic.  In which case, a reality-check tag might be better than, say, science? But if you are asking what can be seen, light is highly relevant to what you are asking.

As to what you would see were you not invisible, you would see reflections of yourself--but how they look and how they repeat would be dependant on how much of a curve the surface has, and if they are separate mirrors connected together.

I think I need to know a little more about how the room is set up to determine the physics of it. However, here are some handy links:

- [where one person on the board talks about how the light might be
  quickly converted into heat](https://www.thenakedscientists.com/forum/index.php?topic=21266.0).
- [this answer, which talks about how light bouncing around in the
  sphere would cause it to have a bright uniform glow as the photons
  bounce about, reflecting back on themselves.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12417/what-happens-to-light-in-a-perfect-reflective-sphere)
- [Take a look at this you tube video starting at 30 seconds for some
  answers, he talks about magnified vision and a person's reflection as
  they go to the center of a sphere. he also talks about how a curved mirror can have an effect of reversing sides--a true reflection](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zRP82omMX0g)